# Unwrap HTML tags keeping only first level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this text

```
"Welcome to my city. <span><span><span>Hello</span> my</span> good</span> friend"
```

Using jQuery (or javascript) I would like to unwrap all span tags keeping only first level, I mean,
the desirable output will be:

```
"Welcome to my city. <span>Hello my good</span> friend"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do it in javascript? In a preprocessor? Server-side? What? Seems like you already unwrapped them yourself :-)

Comment: I guess you didn't see tags "javascript" and "jquery"

Comment: You are right, I missed those. My bad. jQuery could have tipped me off, but javascript could still mean pre-processing.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the HTML by injecting it into an element and then crawl its child nodes, outputting text nodes as they are and converting the content of top-level elements via reading `.textContent` and replacing the `.innerHTML` with that.

```js
function topLevelNodesOnly(html) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;

  let out = '';
  // using [...someVar] converts array-like things into real arrays
  [...div.childNodes].forEach((node) => {
    // if the node is a text node, add it's text to the output string
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      out += node.wholeText;
    } else {
      // if it is anything else, replace it's contents with the text
      // of it's contents
      node.innerHTML = node.textContent;
      // add the html that generated to the output
      out += node.outerHTML;
    }
  });

  return out;
}

console.log(topLevelNodesOnly(`Welcome to my city.  <span class="hello"><span><span>Hello</span> my</span> good</span> friend`));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your text is inside a string you can use regular expressions like this:

```js
var string = 'Welcome to my city. <span id="test"><span><span class="test2">Hello</span> my</span> good</span> friend';
var regex = /<span.*?>(.*)<\/span>/g;

var insideOfSpan = regex.exec(string);

var strippedSpan = insideOfSpan[1].replace(/<\/?span.*?>/g, '');

string = string.replace(/(<span.*?>).*(<\/span>)/, '$1' + strippedSpan + '$2');
console.log(string);
```

Comment: Thanks. But it won't work properly if span tags contain more info like classes, id,

Comment: I updated my answer, now it should work with attributes.

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with RegExp is [almost never a good idea](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/), it's way too fragile and can break quite easily, especially if you get some malformed or malicious HTML.

Comment: I agree, for some reason I thought that's what OP wanted. Rereading the question I have no idea why :) Using DOMParser or creating element like you did in your answer is a much better solution.